# mount: unknown filesystem type 'btrfs'

Tags: debian, mount, raspberry-pi, btrfs

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with a btrfs partition on an external drive. The system is configured to install security updates automatically, but not other updates.

All of a sudden, upon rebooting the system, the btrfs partition no longer mounts. When I try to mount it manually, I get:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'btrfs'
```

Some sources on the net suggested running `modprobe` to ensure btrfs support is installed. `modprobe btrfs` results in:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btrfs': Exec format error
```

What’s wrong here? What can I do to diagnose the issue and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got data corruption. If rebooting doesn't help reinstalling the kernel should help.

If your physical storage has started to die, reinstallation will only help temporarily.

Comment: Indeed, after restoring my SD card (which holds `/` and `/boot`) from a previously saved image, the disk mounts OK again. 24 hours later, everything seems to be working OK again. There’s been a power outage while I was away, so it might be related to that.